# How to use socketio with cordova hybrid app in production?

Tags: cordova, socket.io

I've built and released very simple AjAX/PHP hybrid apps before in the mobile stores (Google and Apple). Now I'm learning nodejs with socketio. I'm using socketio to do [bidirectional](https://socket.io/docs/v4/emitting-events/#Basic-emit) communications (server-to-client and client-to-server). I'm able to work with it fairly well on development machine pointing to localhost.

**Question is** : once the apps are deployed in the mobile stores, how is the server supposed to communicate with the client?

On a development machine it's easy to do since it's local. In development, both the server and apps are on localhost. Server on port 3000 and client-app running on port 8000.

Apps released in stores can't be "pointed" to.

This is my simple app which works well when testing locally on all devices and browsers.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
<title>Myapp</title>
</head>
<body id="app" onload="onLoad()"></body>
</html>
<!--SCRIPTS-->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
//point to localhost server
<script src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

**app.js**

```
// Wait for device API libraries to load
//
function onLoad() {
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {

//testing socket server
serverTest();

}

//testing socketio server
//see socket.js
//
function serverTest() {
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');

socket.on('connect', function() {
socket.on('text', function(text) {

//display data on page    
document.getElementById('app').innerHTML = text;

});
})
}
```

**socket.js**

```
 const path = require('path');
 const express = require('express');
 const app = express();
 const http = require('http');
 const server = http.createServer(app);

 const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
 cors: {
 origin: "http://localhost:8000",
 methods: ["GET", "POST"],
 allowedHeaders: ["my-custom-header"],
 credentials: true
 }
 });
 /**
  * 
  * use the following code to serve images, CSS files, and JavaScript files in a directory
  * https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html
  * 
  */
 app.use(express.static('js'));
 app.use(express.static('css'));
 
 //get
 app.get('/', (req, res,next) => {
 //...
 });
 
 io.on('connection', (socket) => {
 //console 
 console.log('user connected');

 //emitting event
 socket.emit('text', '<p class="serverTest">server and client are communicating </p>');
 
 });
 
 server.listen(3000, () => {
 console.log('listening on *:3000');
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once your in production the process is actually the same, although your socket server is hosted externally.

Once you have that up and running it should work the same just as an external server

Because you mentioned PM2 in your comment, I have updated the answer to also mention, if you are using PM2 for clustering your socket servers you will want to also look at socket.io-redis to manage the sockets across the clusters.

This topic can go fairly deep depending on your use case and make require additional setup to get working right, especially if you need to access socket ID's or get total sockets connected across clusters.

For further reading I have linked to a question I answered a few days ago on that too

[how to access socket session in all clusters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67034796/how-to-access-socket-session-in-all-clusters/67039194?noredirect=1#comment118523275_67039194)

Comment: I'm embarrassed. I thought it was so much more complicated than that because I have to run it with PM2. Same thing, just different language. Logical.

Comment: Don't be :) I had to deep-dive into this stuff last year, was all new to me then and had many of the same questions.. 

You mentioned PM2 in your comment.. this is actually throws a twist that will require you to use socket.io-redis for cluster mode to work, otherwise it will get wonky..